# How to check if bool method returns value in an if statement C++

Tags: c++, function, if-statement

I'm having a go at creating classes and have created this method inside
**Input.cpp:**

```
bool Input::CheckKeyPress(char key)
{
    SDL_Event ev;

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&ev))
    {
        keyState = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

        if (ev.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
            case 'w' :
                if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_W])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            case 'a' :
                if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_A])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            case 's' :
                if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_S])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            case 'd' :
                if (keyState[SDL_SCANCODE_D])
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use it in an if-statement in my main class like so:

```
if (bool Input::CheckKeyPress(w))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
```

However as expected I get an error saying: "**A function type is not allowed here**" So what do I do?

Comment: get rid of `bool` in the if condition

Comment: what is `Input`?

Comment: In the statements `if (keyState[...` you already use the fact that the `keyState` values are  convertible to bool, so you could just as well just do `return (keyState[...`.

Comment: is `Input::CheckKeyPress` `static`? If not you probably need an `Input` instance instead of `Input::`

Comment: @user4581301 how would I create the input instance? - Sorry, noob here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write:

```
if (CheckKeyPress(w))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

You have already told the compiler that the `CheckKeyPress()` method returns a `bool`.  Here, you are just calling the function, so you don't need to mention the return type again.  When the control will call the function `CheckKeyPress()`, it will return a `bool` value that would be checked for its truth within the `if` statement.

**Note:** There are two possibilities:

1. `Instance` is a different class:

If `Instance` is altogether a different class and `CheckKeyPress()` is 
one of the methods that it contains, then you first need to create an object of the `Instance` class like below:

```
Instance it = new Instance();   //or just Instance it;
```

and then access the function via:

```
it.CheckKeyPress();
```

2. If the method is `static`:

In this case you need to call the method as:

```
Input::CheckKeyPress(w)
```

without just the return type (`bool`).

Hope this is helpful.  Thank you for your inputs, @user4581301.

Comment: Almost. It doesn't sound like OP is calling `CheckKeyPress` from inside `Input`, so they either need an `Input` instance or OPs `Input::` if it's static.

Comment: I agree.  But I have posted the answer as per what content the OP *has posted*.  I will still edit it for both the cases, though.  Thank you.

Comment: Big fan of solving the whole problem. Otherwise you [get Vampired](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) as OP keep coming back asking about the little bits you left out.

Comment: Thanks for solving this problem for me too, I understand it can be annoying have noobs post their questions on StackExchange, sorry about that.

Comment: `Instance it = new Instance();` - This isn't valid C++ (unless your class is poorly designed).

Comment: @chris, could you please elaborate?  Are you referring to the `new` operator?

Comment: Yes, C++ doesn't create objects only through `new` like Java. `Instance it;` is enough.

Comment: I totally agree.  I just used dynamic initialization.  Nonetheless, I will update my answer to reflect your point as well.  Thank you.